# Does adding CDN stops Google from crawling?

Tags: web-crawlers, googlebot, cdn

I want to add Cloudflare free CDN to my site but worried about whether Google bots will be able to crawl my site later on or not.

Comment: Why would it stop Google crawling your site? considering its used by over a million websites. Cloudflare acts as a proxy, everything that is crawlable will continue to be crawlable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Incapsula, some of the benefits of using a CDN include:

Faster load times for content on your site (this is especially useful for increasing performance of your mobile site)
Image compression improves performance by reducing the size of images sent to the user
Session optimization reduces the number of open connections to your web server
Scaling quickly when there is increased or heavy traffic to your website
Ensuring the stability of your website by minimizing the risk of traffic spikes at point of origin
Better site performance and customer experience.

With all these I only see its benefit so why would google look over these and not crawl cdn website.

[Benifits from here see more effect on seo here](https://www.searchenginejournal.com/content-delivery-networks-cdns-can-impact-seo/143595/)